# Table updates from JSON array but sorting alphabetically causes error in Swift 3

Tags: ios, swift

In my iOS app, I populate a table from an external json file. That works fine now, the problem I am running into is that I need to sort the table alphabetically.

I've added a compare method, and printing it will give me the correct output (a list of results organized by their `show_name`). However, when I try to append those results to the table, I get an error.

Here's my code:

```
func extract_json(_ data: Data)
{
    let json: Any?
    do{
        json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: [])
    }
    catch{
        return
    }

    guard let data_list = json as? NSArray else {
        return
    }

    if let shows_list = json as? NSArray
    {
        for i in 0 ..< data_list.count
        {
            if let shows_obj = shows_list[i] as? NSDictionary
            {
                let show_name = shows_obj["show"] as? String
                let show_image = shows_obj["thumbnail"] as? String
                TableData.append(show_name!)
                var sortedArray = TableData.sorted { $0.localizedCaseInsensitiveCompare($1) == ComparisonResult.orderedAscending }
                print(sortedArray)
```

If I change the `TableData.append(show_name!)` to `TableData.append(sortedArray)`, I get the error "Cannot convert value of type '[String]?' to expected argument type 'String'".

Is there a safer/smarter way to alphabetize my json array by an attribute before loading it into the table (than trying to load it into the TableData and then comparing, like I am now)?

Comment: You should unwrap `sortedArray` first, and then call `append(contentsOf:)` instead of `append`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think `TableData` is the array of `String` and you are trying to append `String Array` in it. That is the reason you are getting this error.

You should do like this,

```
TableData.append(contentsOf: sortedArray)
```

Comment: downvote doesn't make sense, please provide reason for downvote also